# C# and SQL - Must declare the scalar variable writing to DB

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've been at this for hours and can't catch a break. I'm writing this program in C# which connects to a database and writes new rows each time new sensor readings are available. The Function snippet that writes a new row to the DB is below.

When I run my code I continue to get the following run-time error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@dbSpeed".

I started having this issue when I switched from using a regular old array to a Dictionary, but I'm not sure that is the cause of this.

```
private void WriteDataRowtoSQL(Dictionary<string, double> dataPoints)
{
     //SQL Database Connection String.
    string dataSource = @"Data Source=TSCRPC\TSCRPCDB;Initial Catalog=TSCRPCDB;Integrated Security=True";

    //SQL Database Query Command Build to insert sensor data as rows.  
    string sensorDataRowItems = "(Date,Time,Mac_State,S_GainStatus,S_Speed,S_Direction,S_Temperature,S_Humidity,S_PowerOutput,S_Current,S_Voltage,S_EngineRPM,S_NoiseLevel,S_BatteryVolts,S_TorkStrain1,S_TorkStrain2,S_WheelStrain,S_Vibration1,S_Vibration2,S_BreakPressure)";
    string cmdString = "INSERT INTO SensorData " + sensorDataRowItems + " VALUES (@dbDate, @dbTime, @dbMacState, @dbGainStatus, @dbSpeed, @dbDirection, @dbTemperature, @dbHumidity, @dbPowerOutput, @dbCurrent, @dbVoltage, @dbEngineRPM, @dbNoiseLevel, @dbBatteryVolts, @dbTorkStrain1, @dbTorkStrain2, @dbWheelStrain, @dbVibration1, @dbVibration2, @dbBreakPressure)";

    //Connect to and use SQL DB.
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(dataSource))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
        {
            comm.Connection = sqlConn;
            comm.CommandText = cmdString;

            if (dataPoints.ContainsKey("Gain Status") == true)
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbGainStatus", true); 
            }
            else if (dataPoints.ContainsKey("Battery Voltage") == true)
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbBatteryVolts", dataPoints["Battery Voltage"]);
            }
            else if (dataPoints.ContainsKey("Break Line Pressure") == true)
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbBreakPressure", dataPoints["Break Line Pressure"]);
            }
            else if (dataPoints.ContainsKey("Volts") == true)
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbVoltage", dataPoints["Volts"]);
            }
            else if (dataPoints.ContainsKey("Current") == true)
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbCurrent", dataPoints["Current"]);
            }
            else if (dataPoints.ContainsKey("Vibration") == true)
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbVibration1", dataPoints["Vibration"]);
            }
            else if (dataPoints.ContainsKey("Tork Strain 1") == true)
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbTorkStrain1", dataPoints["Tork Strain 1"]);
            }
            else if (dataPoints.ContainsKey("Tork Strain 2") == true)
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbTorkStrain2", dataPoints["Tork Strain 2"]);
            }
            else if (dataPoints.ContainsKey("Speed") == true)
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbSpeed", dataPoints["Speed"]);
            }
            else if (dataPoints.ContainsKey("Engine RPM") == true)
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbEngineRPM", dataPoints["Engine RPM"]);
            }

            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy"));
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbTime", DateTime.Now.ToString("H:m:s:fff"));
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbMacState", true);  
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbDirection", 22);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbTemperature", 22);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbHumidity", 22);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbPowerOutput", 22);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbNoiseLevel", 22);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbVibration2", 22);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbWheelStrain", 22);

            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: You need to add all parameters to the command even if they don't have a value.  You can use `DBNull.Value` to represent a null value.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Thanks for the help D Stanley.  That solved my issue.  .

Comment: marc_s, I'll check out the article, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add all parameters in the query even if they don't have a value.  Change

```
if (dataPoints.ContainsKey("Gain Status") == true)
{
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbGainStatus", true); 
}
```

to something like

```
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbGainStatus", 
    dataPoints.ContainsKey("Gain Status") ? (object)true : DBNull.Value);
```

And so on for each parameter (changing `true` to the value you intend to use)

Comment: And for OP's error, OP should use it for `@dbSpeed` parameter.

Comment: @shA.t It's probably just coincidence that the `Speed` parameter is the first one that was missing - it should be added to _all_ parameters.

Comment: You were right, it was a problem across the board.  I corrected all of them and then it all started working as expected.   Thanks again for your quick response.